# input and authentication validation in microservices and api-gateway architecture

Tags: node.js, express, microservices, gateway

in short, where the input validation and authentication validation should be executed?
In api-gateway and each microservice? only in api-gateway? only in each microservice?

Maybe part of it in api-gateway and part in each?

Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, validation should be put as near to client as possible in order to [fail fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) but without compromising the architecture and responsibilities of each component/microservice.

That being said, you could put authentication in the API Gateway but *input validation is specific to each microservice* and I don't think that you can centralize that into the API Gateway. Also, there are too many types of validation that can exist to give an accurate answer about them but you could try to apply the rule in the first paragraph as much as you can.